# Error on CMDEXEC job step even with proxy account defined

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

I’m not yet used to managing permissions on SQL Server 2008. I’m currently trying to create a SQL Server job directly from SQL with a user that isn’t sysadmin (but has the role **SQLAgentUserRole**). Let’s call him **MyUser**.

For some reason, each time I try to execute a job step using the subsystem CMDEXEC, I get an error saying "*Non-SysAdmins have been denied permission to run CmdExec job steps without a proxy account.  The step failed.*". As for TSQL steps, they always work fine.

Here is my configuration:

- **MyUser** has granted access to the proxy account named **MyProxy**.
- **MyProxy** has granted access to the subsystem "CMDEXEC" and is linked to a credential also called **MyProxy**.
- The credential **MyProxy** is linked to the login **MyLogin**.
- **MyLogin** is sysadmin on SQL Server, and admin on Windows.

Is there anything I missed? Why do I keep getting that error? What other permissions should I configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Run As in your job step to MyProxy so the job step will use the proxy.